# Code blocks in user profile descriptions show up empty

Tags: support, status-bydesign, profile-page, design

When viewing [this user's profile](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/1186/lfzawacki) on Music, I saw the following:

[image: screenshot]

That empty area is a list of items, but it's indented four space so it looks like a code block.  Except it's showing up as empty instead of displaying the contents in monospace.

<strike>I'm not sure if t</strike>This is related to Music's jTab plugin <strike>or not, so I'm posting this here</strike> so I've [posted it there](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/code-blocks-in-user-profile-descriptions-show-up-empty); feel free to close this.

Comment: No repro on MSO for me...maybe this should be on the appropriate Meta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem must be caused by a Javascript plugin that runs on that specific site. If I look at the source of that user profile, I notice the following HTML tags.

```
<pre><code>Ruby
RoR
C, C++
Lua
</code></pre>
```

If I look at the page using the Safari's Web Inspector, the HTML tags it finds are the following ones.

[image: screenshot]

The content of the `<code>` tag is replaced with a `<svg>` tag.

That is not what happen in other SE sites, for example on this very site.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, I'll post it on Music's meta then.